# How to display a vertical "time" line over a visual made in PowerBi?

Tags: python, animation, powerbi, data-visualization

I have a Gannt chart that basically represents the timeline for the scheduled operations that need to be performed through out the day and I am looking for a way to display a vertical line corresponding to the time that it is right now. I am quite new to data visualization and don't know a lot. What I was thinking is to either put an animation of the vertical line that would slide over my timeline (I would take an image of the visual from power bi) or start with scratch and program the visual in Python instead of the PowerBi and customize it from there. In any of the above cases, I don't really know how to implement it and would appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this. I will provide an image of the chart itself for a better understanding of the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement a custom python generated chart, although you are limited to the imports; matplotlib, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy, seaborn and statsmodels for constructing these visuals.

However, there is a Gantt chart import that you can get from the power bi marketplace (free). It is called **Gantt 2.2.3** and will allow for you to add in the today line that you are looking for. This is probably the easiest approach.

Thanks